# want to use canvas here as background

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, canvas

I attempt to use [this animation](http://cssdeck.com/labs/4ksohwya) as background (actually just put a few text on it by using page-warp). I know that it is possible to use canvas as background. However, I have tired with those but only to get fully black background. I have sit 2h already tried to figure this out but nothing come to my mind. need some idea and help.

Comment: where is the test code that you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Canvas clears itself when resized

(element.width or element.height has changed)

draw when window has resized.

You can use

```
canvas {
  object-fit: contain;
  /* object-fit: cover */
}
```

to fix aspect ratio problems.